# Concurrent Multithreaded Server through UDP in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, udp

I am trying to build a server which can handle multiple requests at the same time on same port number through UDP. Below is java code for the same.

```
Runnable task = () ->
                {
                    DatagramSocket aSocket=null;
                    while(true)
                    { 
                        try
                        {  
                        aSocket= new DatagramSocket(2222);
                        byte[] buffer=new byte[1000]; 
                        DatagramPacket Reply=new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);

                        aSocket.receive(Reply);
                        String rec=new String(Reply.getData());
                        System.out.println("rec "+rec);

                        String[] splited = rec.split("\\s+");

                        System.out.println("Operation "+splited[0]);
                        if(splited[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Enroll"))
                        {
                            String ret=cs.enrollCourse(splited[1],splited[2],splited[3]);
                            byte[] temp=new byte[1000];
                            temp=ret.getBytes();
                            DatagramPacket se=new DatagramPacket(temp,temp.length,Reply.getAddress(),Reply.getPort());
                            aSocket.send(se);

                        }
                       if(splited[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Drop"))
                       {
                           String ret=cs.drop_external(splited[1],splited[2]);
                           byte[] temp=new byte[1000];
                           temp=ret.getBytes();
                           DatagramPacket se=new DatagramPacket(temp,temp.length,Reply.getAddress(),Reply.getPort());
                           aSocket.send(se);
                           aSocket.close();

                        }
                        if(splited[0].equalsIgnoreCase("list"))
                        {
                            String ret=cs.listCourseAvailability(splited[1],splited[2]);
                            byte[] temp=new byte[1000];
                            temp=ret.getBytes();
                            DatagramPacket se=new DatagramPacket(temp,temp.length,Reply.getAddress(),Reply.getPort());
                            aSocket.send(se);

                         }
                         if(splited[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Remove"))
                         {
                            String ret=cs.removeCourse(splited[1],splited[2]);
                            byte[] temp=new byte[1000];
                            temp=ret.getBytes();
                            DatagramPacket se=new DatagramPacket(temp,temp.length,Reply.getAddress(),Reply.getPort());
                            aSocket.send(se);

                         }

                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                       if (aSocket != null)
                        {
                            aSocket.close();
                        }
                    }
                  }
            };
       Thread t=new Thread(task);
       t.start();
```

When two request arrives at the same time, one of them is not being received by the above code.

Is the implementation correct? Is there any other way to implement the same using UDP?

Answer (score 0):

After each incoming packet is processed and the reply is sent, you are closing the `DatagramSocket` an opening a new one.  This will (probably) cause the OS to discard any packets that have been received and not processed.

Solution:  don't do that.  Use a single `DatagramSocket` and only close it when the thread is about to exit.

In fact, the thread is not serving any real purpose here ... though that's not the cause of your problem.